# Appending child nodes to parent nodes in D3 sankey

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Currently, I am working on clubbing together all the child nodes together in a rectangle rather than creating a seperate parent circle for future reference. Following is an example of the sankey chart i am working on:
[bi-directional sankey chart by Neilos.](http://bl.ocks.org/Neilos/584b9a5d44d5fe00f779)

However i am not able to understand the logic used for collapsers here. For example:

```
collapser = svg.select("#collapsers").selectAll(".collapser")
    .data(biHiSankey.expandedNodes(), function (d) { return d.id; });
```

This will create collapser to which you will append the circle. Now, is there any way we can append all the child nodes to this circle(by making it big enough), so that graphically we can show that all the child nodes belong to same parent class?

At line 433 of the default sankey code you see:

```
 collapserEnter.append("circle")
.attr("r", 100)
.style("fill", function (d) {
  d.color = colorScale(d.type.replace(/ .*/, ""));
  return d.color;
});
```

Does this mean than i can try appending the child nodes to this collapserEnter object? If not, is there any other way we can do it?
All help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can't nest SVG elements inside a `<circle>`; you would need to create a `<g>` instead of circles. Then put append the circle and the nodes inside it. You can read about [nested selections](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) for info on how to use data bindings for this. So essentially you'd be layering a circle and some nodes inside of a `<g>`.

Comment: It's worth asking whether nesting is appropriate. For example, if there are nodes that are supposed to flow into nodes outside of their parent `<g>` container, it could be a problem. Maybe it would be less complicated if you stay with a flat hierarchy but tweak the layout to make it look like circles contain nodes simply by setting their positions accordingly. Not sure how applicable this is, because it's not clear exactly what you're trying to achieve.